# How to add Choice Field to Django forms for user registration?

Tags: django, django-forms, user-registration

I am making a registration form for 3 types of users. When a user enters email and password he/she must select one of the roles.
First I used BooleanFields and it works, but more than one checkbox can be selected. I need that user can select only one role.
I have tried ChoiceField, which I could display on the template but it does not POST any data to db.

***forms.py***

```
class RegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """A form for creating new users. Includes all the required
    fields, plus a repeated password."""
    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Password confirmation', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    parent = forms.BooleanField(label="I am a Parent")
    school = forms.BooleanField(label="I am a School Admin")
    vendor = forms.BooleanField(label="I am a Vendor")

    role_select=forms.ChoiceField(
                    widget=forms.RadioSelect,
                    label="Select your role.",
                    choices=(('is_parent','parent '),('is_school','school'),('is_vendor','vendor')),
                    )

    if not parent and not school and not vendor:
        raise forms.ValidationError("Users must have a role")

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['role_select', 'parent', 'school', 'vendor', 'email'] #'full_name',)


    def clean_password2(self):
        # Check that the two password entries match
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords don't match")
        return password2

    def save(self, commit=True):
        # Save the provided password in hashed format
        user = super(RegisterForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
        user.role_select( self.cleaned_data['role_select'])
        # user.active = False # send confirmation email
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

As you see in the forms.py I have a combination of two approaches. So it has some useless lines. Which approach to use and how?

Answer (score 1):

you can use Django groups where you can create a group and assign it as a choicefield when user registers. You can check my repository. I have done the same thing here. Hope it can get you some idea

https://github.com/tsephel/User-authentication-django-/tree/master/env